# How to multiply two tensor with arbitrary ranks, on one index only (like GR)?

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors, products, inner

I am writing a function which take two tensors with the same dimensions but with arbitrary ranks and multiplies them over one index, just like this example from GR:

[image]

See, I couldn't use `Table` since I don't know the ranks r, which may be very large for me to explicitly write all configurations. If all inputs had the same ranks, this would be a simple sum inside table, with r ranges:

[image]

Please let me know if you know a clever way of doing this, for example by using `TensorProduct`, `Inner`, `Outer`, etc.

Comment: Maybe this package can be useful: http://www.xact.es/

Comment: Mattiav27, I know about this package, but I like to have a self-contained code.

Comment: Using the answer, I got it to work for that example. Can you explain the process of index shifting please? Is it switching the last index with the one we are summing over? I think other people would like to see your explanation if you add it to above answer of yours. Thanks! – Milad P. 6 hours ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs of `Inner`:

> Inner[f,Subscript[list, 1],Subscript[list, 2],g,n] contracts index n
>   of the first tensor with the first index of the second tensor.

This means that you can leave the first tensor argument as-is, and specify which of its indices you want to contract in the fifth argument of `Inner`, but then you have to `Transpose` the second tensor so that the index to contract is the first.

So in your case you could either do

```
v1 = Inner[Times, g, Transpose[T], Plus, 2]
```

Then if the parts of `g` are `g[[j, m]]` and the parts of `T` are `T[[i, m, k]]` the parts of `v1` will be

```
v1[[j, i, k]]
```

Or you can do

```
v2 = Inner[Times, T, Transpose[g], 2]
```

Such that we have

```
v1[[i, k, j]]
```

In general, if we want to contract index number `n1` of tensor `t1` with index number `n2` of tensor `t2`, we may use the code

```
tensorContract[t1_, t2_, n1_, n2_] := 
  With[{t2transpose = Transpose[t2, ReplacePart[Range[ArrayDepth[t2]], 1 -> n2, n2 -> 1]]},
  Inner[Times, t1, t2transpose, Plus, n1]
]
```

If the indices of `t1` were

```
{i[1], i[2], ..., i[n1-1], i[n1], i[n1+1], ..., i[r1]}
```

and the indices of `t2` were

```
{j[1], j[2], ..., j[n2-1], j[n2], j[n2+1], ... j[r2]}
```

then the indices of the answer produced by the above function will be

```
{i[1], ..., i[n1-1], i[n1+1], ..., i[r1], j[1], ..., j[n2-1], j[n2+1], ..., j[r2]}
```

Comment: Don't I need to take a final transpose of Inner[...]?

Comment: And why do you have g first and T second? Doesn't 2 specify the index for the FIRST list, not the second one?

Comment: In your post it seems that `m`, the index to contract, is the second index of both `g` and `T`, no? So that will be correct no matter the order. I have included both orders, `g, T` and `T, g` in my post... And I'm showing how the indices come out if we do it both ways. If you want the indices of the result in any specific order, e.g. `[[k, i, j]]`, you can of course `Transpose` in the end if you like.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work for that example. Can you explain the process of index shifting please? Is it switching the last index with the one we are summing over? I think other people would like to see your explanation if you add it to above answer of yours. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful. I'll definitely mention you in the GR package I'm writing.